# Assigning form values in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I have a challenge and I need help.
I am trying to integrate a payment system and I got some stuck, I have something like this:

```
options: PaystackOptions= {
 amount: 5000,
 email: 'user@email.com',
 ref: `'some code that generate random stuff'`
```

Some methods other.

Now when I use hard coded values it works fine but doesn't work when I attempts to assign values from my form. My question is how do I assign values from my reactive form to the above for it to work. When I console log the form values , there are values.

I try assigning values like this in my onSubmit method where the Payments is still initiated that is I have one button where I called the onSubmit method and Initiated the Payment.

```
this.options.amount = this.donateForm.value['amount'];
this.options.email = this.donateForm.value['email'];
```

When I console log **this.options.amount** , the value is there but somehow doesn't get passed to **options** when I assign it, I know this is not a better explanation for my problem but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Williams, welcom to Stackoverflow! Could you please edit your text again? It seems that highlighting of code and normal text got mixed up somehow. This way it is kind of hard to interpret your question.

Comment: please put down the code what you have used, i'm sure we could help!

Comment: Yes, sample code in something like stackBlitz will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your requirement, see if the following help to fix your issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sdkh8q